# Stream large file from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

We have a web API that produces large files (up to 10 GB).
I am building an endpoint that will provide a file to the client.
There is a cloud-front server between the API and the client.
My current implementation has several issues I need to solve.
We are using .NET Core 3.1.
The service is hosted in IIS.

The code in the controller is:

```cs
return File(
    new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
    ContentType.ApplicationOctetStream,
    filename);
```

1. Getting the 504 response from the cloud-front server. The configured timeout is 60 seconds.
2. Getting out-of-memory exception on the server.

**Questions:**

- Is there anything I need to add to the headers to make it come through the cloud-front server?
- Should I use a different result type? I tried PhysicalFile() with the same results.
- Are there any settings I should check on the cloud-front side?
- Can be the problem on the client side? I have tested that via swagger and postman with the same result.
- Is there a way I can limit the amount of memory the endpoint can use? The host machine is very limited in resources.

Comment: You will need to increase or remove the timeout and response limit.  I think on .net core 3.1 you can do this on kestrel server.  If its hosted on IIS then you might hit another layer of timeouts and request limits depending on how IIS is setup(you will need to look this up).

If you remove them it theory it should work, but do you think this is the best transport for such files?  For example could this sit on azure storage or SFTP, reason I say this is that they can resume downloading most of the time if interrupted, what happens if this API request fails? start the download again?

Comment: The timeout comes from the cloud-front, not the service itself. The cloud-front timeout has max value of 180 seconds.
I cannot change the infrastructure. If the download fails, it fails. We'll need to start again.